# Nuxt how to override global css for a page

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a project with multiple layouts, I have added the CSS globally in `nuxt.config.js` file like this:

```js
  css: [
    '@/assets/plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css',
    '@/assets/plugins/ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css',
    '@/assets/plugins/feather/feather.css',
    '@/assets/css/style.css',
    '@/assets/css/custom-style.css',
    '@/assets/css/skins.css',
  ]
```

but I want for just 1 layout to remove all css imported because the file being served is a static HTML file with all the styles inline.

Is this possible in nuxt and if not, what is the best possible workaround?

Answer (score 2):

You could add the css files in your layout in a normal style block and not in nuxt.config.js.

```
<style lang="scss">
@import ...;
</style>
```

Then you can use another layout without these css files.

Comment: But this way I will have to edit all the layouts and add the imports in all the layouts except just 1. I thought there is an easy way to tell nuxt to remove all imports from this 1 layout.

Comment: I am only guessing but as  nuxt.conf.js is global I think it is not possible.

You can add all imports of your files in one scss and import only this instead of many CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the scope from your style on the .vue file where you want to override the global style:

```
 <style s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶d̶>
.ProseMirror p {
  color: rgb(236, 10, 10);
}
</style>
```

I wonder too, if you would be better off creating new vue layout files in the layout folder and applying those styles to the pages you want to affect globally, instead of pulling the css through nuxt.config.js file.  Then, on the specific page that you want to override the global style, just remove the scope as I mention above. Just a thought.